# Simplify doesn't simplify multiple conditions from Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

Consider the following simple example where I try to solve an equation and then apply a bounded interval to find the right result out of an infinite amount of solutions:

```
Eq4 = -1 == (Cos[δ] Sin[t])/(Cos[φ ] Sin[δ] - Cos[t] Cos[δ] Sin[φ])    
tS = Simplify[(Reduce[Eq4, {t}] /. {δ -> -0.401426, φ -> 0.841248699}) && (0 < t < π/2)]

(* Out:
C[1] ∈ Integers && (t == -2.72982 + 2 π C[1] || t == 0.869424 + 2 π C[1]) && 0 < t < π/2
*)
```

Why isn't the last one just simplified to `t == 0.869424` and how can I achieve it?

Comment: `First@Solve[0 <= t <= \[Pi]/2 && Reduce[Eq4, {t}] /. {\[Delta] -> -0.401426, \[CurlyPhi] -> 0.841248699}, {t, C[1]}]`

Comment: You can simply include the domain restriction in your system of equations instead. A simple `Reduce[{Eq4, 0 < t < Pi/2} /. {δ -> -0.401426, φ -> 0.841248699}, t]` readily returns `t == 0.869424`.

Comment: @MarcoB and march: Both of your solutions work. However in both cases I get the warning "Solve/Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.".
It would be nice, but not necessary to get rid of it.
If you post your comments as answers I'll accept (one of) them.

Comment: @march see above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply include the domain restriction in your system of equations instead:

```
Eq4 = -1 == (Cos[δ] Sin[t])/(Cos[φ ] Sin[δ] - Cos[t] Cos[δ] Sin[φ])    
Reduce[{Eq4, 0 < t < Pi/2} /. {δ -> -0.401426, φ -> 0.841248699}, t] 
(* Out: t == 0.869424 *)
```

`Reduce` complains that it "was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result". That really does not influence the result you get in this case, but if it bothers you, you could

1) provide exact values for δ and φ;

2) `Rationalize` the numerical ones you have as follows:

```
Reduce[{Eq4, 0 < t < Pi/2} /. Rationalize[{δ -> -0.401426, φ -> 0.841248699}, 0], t] // N
(* Out: t == 0.869424 *)
```

3) simply suppress the printing of the message using `Quiet`:

```
Quiet@Reduce[{Eq4, 0 < t < Pi/2} /. {δ -> -0.401426, φ -> 0.841248699}, t]
```